# ADB 'su: permission denied' in recovery mode on rooted device

Tags: adb, recovery-mode, root-access, file-permissions, superuser

ADB 'su' command returns 'su: permission denied' on a fully rooted device in recovery mode. I can modify folders and files that require root access on phone (when it's booted). ADB also works when it's booted - I only need to confirm a superuser pop-up on the phone.

USB debugging is enabled.

What can the problem be?

Thanks!

Comment: What device are you referring to?

Comment: What is the exact command you are using? You should be able to 'adb shell' into the phone and once inside, simply run 'su'.

Answer (score 2):

Most recoveries don't work in root mode - and root mode cannot be acheived, as the SU binary calls your superuser app to gain permission to use root mode.

As the `su` binary cannot call the app, it stops you using SU mode.

It could also be due to the fact that the `su` file used in recovery is the stock `su` file found in Android, and this doesn't let you switch to the root user (as if it did every device would be rooted).

Some recoveries allow root to be used - you will have to search for one for your device.

Answer (score 1):

You are not going to get a popup superuser confirmation from within a rooted recovery.

That popup superuser confirm dialog only happens in a fully booted *normal* Android environment.

Sounds more likely that the ramdisk used within the recovery, has the setting `ro.secure=1` in `default.prop` by accident thus preventing the su binary from getting executed with a error `su: permission denied`.

Had it being set as `ro.secure=0` then adb would allow the **s** witch **u** ser to root function as normal.

**OP:** Please give more details such as make of handset, what version of recovery, is it clockworkmod or stock?